# How to add new empty line in place of deleted one when compering using linux diff

Tags: linux, compare, text-files, diff

I have two files a.txt and b.txt

**a.txt** content

```
a
b
c
```

**b.txt** content

```
a
c
d
```

I need file **c.txt** with following content:

```
a

c
d
```

File b.txt does not have b line but has extra d line. 
File c.txt has empty line in place of missing b and has new line d.

How can i achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's using `sed` to modify the output of `diff -u`:

```
$ diff -u a.txt b.txt
--- a.txt   2016-07-26 18:27:59.000000000 +0200
+++ b.txt   2016-07-26 18:28:05.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 a
-b
 c
+d
```

We'd like to remove the three first lines of that output, then replace every line that starts with a `-` with a blank line. Finally we need to remove the first character from each remaining line:

```
$ diff -u a.txt b.txt | sed  -e '1,3d' -e 's/^-.*$//' -e 's/^.//'
a

c
d
```

This may fail if `diff` finds too many similar lines in between the differing lines, in which case it will print a new `@@`-line. We may solve this by asking for more lines of unified context with `-U`:

```
$ diff -u -U 100 a.txt b.txt | sed  -e '1,3d' -e 's/^-.*$//' -e 's/^.//'
```